# Почему не сохраняет новое значение в словаре (в цикле)?

Tags: python, словари

Почему-то не сохраняет новое значение в словаре

```
def my_func():
    """
    
    """
    peremenaya_1 = 'test_1'   # !!!
    peremenaya_2 = 114        # !!!
    peremenaya_3 = ''         # <--- необходимо будет обновить это значение

    loc_dict = locals()

    for value in loc_dict:
        print(f'{type(value)}, {value},{loc_dict[value]}')
        if loc_dict[value] == '':    
            print(f'find empty element {loc_dict[value]=}')
            loc_dict[value] == 'xxx'     # !!! почему то не сохраняет новое значение 
        else:
            print(f'this: {loc_dict[value]}')

    print(f'\nloc_dict new = {loc_dict}')
    

my_func()
```

Comment: из документации `Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.`

Comment: понятно теперь (

Comment: @almaz так просто надо одно равно написать `loc_dict[value] = 'xxx'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы случайно написали `==` а надо просто `=`

```
def my_func():
    """
    
    """
    peremenaya_1 = 'test_1'   # !!!
    peremenaya_2 = 114        # !!!
    peremenaya_3 = ''         # <--- необходимо будет обновить это значение

    loc_dict = locals()

    for value in loc_dict:
        print(f'{type(value)}, {value},{loc_dict[value]}')
        if loc_dict[value] == '':    
            print(f'find empty element {loc_dict[value]=}')
            loc_dict[value] = 'xxx'     # одно равно
        else:
            print(f'this: {loc_dict[value]}')

    print(f'\nloc_dict new = {loc_dict}')
    

my_func()
```

Comment: вот Спасибо Вам :)) недоглядел )